# phpthumb remove cache for specific file

Tags: caching, rotation, phpthumb, purge

I'm using the library phpthumb for resizing image on the fly on a personal project.
I give the users the abilities to modify the image they have uploaded and rotate it.
I need to purge the phpthumb cache of the specific image. How can i do this?

thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1):

ok I finally found it,
in order to refresh the cache of an image we can add a hash parameter like this:

```
<img src="/uploads/phpThumb.php?src=/uploads/photo/myimage.jpg&w=250&ar=x&hash=<?php echo time(); ?>" alt="#"/>
```